# build-local.mk: No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin

Please help, I have a very wierd error here, while I trying to compile project. Console says:

> 03:17:23 **** Auto Build of configuration Default for project
>   MyProject *** bash ndk-build all  make.exe:
>   C:\workspace/MyProject/build/core/build-local.mk: No such file or
>   directory make.exe: ** No rule to make target
>   `C:\workspace/MyProject/build/core/build-local.mk'.  Stop.
>
> 03:17:24 Build Finished (took 654ms)

So I'm trying compile code from book "Android NDK for Beginnners". First of all, an author telling to convert java project to C++ project. Once I did it - an error appears. To fix it I need to build library with **ndk-build** , an autor  offers to make changes in project properties, exactly go to **Builders** and change default build command to **ndk-build**, but thats woun't work without **bash** word before it. So when I figured that out and tried to build the project - an error occures.

Help please, I can' find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your book is probably outdated, or it does not address Windows environment. On Windows, instead of `ndk-build` command or `bash ndk-build`, use `ndk-build.cmd`. Download and ise the latest version of NDK.